# Loginviewcontroller before SWRevealviewcontroller with Storyboard objective C

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewcontroller` by using this [sample](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/):

> I want to add loginviewcontroller before SWRevealViewcontroller.

What I've tried:

1. Added loginviewcontroller in `Storyboard`. Set it as `InitialViewcontroller`.
2. Inside button action.

   ```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   MapViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];

   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
   [navController setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];

   [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
   [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
   ```

But it is not working. Please help

Comment: After loginView it goes to next ViewController and in next ViewController you want SWReavelViewController.. am i Right @iosdeveloper..??

Comment: @SurajSukale Yes. I want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**viewController1**

```
viewController2 *viewController2=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2Id"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController2 animated:YES];
```

**viewController2**

```
-(void)pushAfterLoginScreen
{
SidebarViewController *sidebarmemu =(SidebarViewController*)    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SidebarController"];

viewController3* viewController3 = (viewController2*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController2Id"];

SWRevealViewController *revealController;
UINavigationController *frontNavigationController;
UINavigationController *rearNavigationController;
frontNavigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: viewController2];
rearNavigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:sidebarmemu];
revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
revealController.delegate = self;
self.swcontroller =revealController;
AppDelegate *app =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
app.window.rootViewController =self.swcontroller;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.   What is  self.swcontroller  ?

Comment: @property(strong,nonatomic)SWRevealViewController *swcontroller;

Answer (score 1):

`SWRevealViewcontroller` which is already embed with the `navigationController` you need to pass control to `SWRevealViewcontroller` after successful login using `presentViewController` method by setting up the storyboard id to `navigationController` of `SWRevealViewcontroller` and navigate your app using below code:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navContStoryboardID"];
[vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCustom];  // optional
[vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];  // optional
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps you.